# inexplicable math error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function, used to clone the flash article scroller [this page](http://www.goldcoast.com.au/about-the-gold-coast.html). Unfortunately I'm behind a firewall so can't upload my own code, but that should give you an idea. The function:

```
function select(id) {
  alert(active+"\n"+((active+1)%4));

  var prev  =  active;
  active    = (typeof(id) == "undefined" ? (active+1)%4 : id);

  $("#panel").animate({"top": tops[active]}, 750);
  $("#main"+prev).fadeOut(750);
  $("#main"+active).fadeIn(750);
}
```

So if select() is called without an id, it simply progresses to the next item in sequence, otherwise it goes to the selected item. It's run on a timer defined:

```
timer = setInterval("select()", 5000);
```

When an object is mouseovered, this function is run:

```
$("img.thumb").mouseover(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  select($(this).attr("id").substr(-1));
  timer = setInterval("select()", 5000);
});
```

The trouble is that, after a mouseover, the select function fails for one cycle, with the next object having no relation to the previous. The chosen object is consistent - it remains the same with each refresh given the same initial conditions, but it's unrelated in any way I can determine.

What is oddest is that the alert I run at the start of select(), which should be a straightforward mathematical operation, fails, claiming that (for the sequence I test - wait for an automatic scroll from 0 - 1, then mouseover 3) (3+1)%4=3.

I've tested this in both firefox and chrome, so it seems to be inherent to javascript.

I can only assume that it's storing two different values for active somehow, but nature of that schism, and how to resolve it, are beyond me.

I've attached the entire file below in case anything else is pertinent. Seems unlikely, but at this point I'm not ruling anything out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //alter these as you please
            var thumbs  = ["images/1t.png", "images/2t.png",
                "images/3t.png", "images/4t.png"];
            var mains       = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png",
                "images/3.png", "images/4.png"];
            var links       = ["http://www.goldcoast.com.au/gold-coast-beaches.html",
                "http://www.goldcoast.com.au/gold-coast-whale-watching.html",
                "http://www.goldcoast.com.au/gold-coast-hinterland-rainforest.html",
                "http://www.goldcoast.com.au/gold-coast-history.html"];

            //don't touch these
            var timer   = null;
            var active  = 0;
            var tops    = [0, 77, 155, 234];

            function select(id) {
                alert(active+"\n"+((active+1)%4));

                var prev    =  active;
                active      = (typeof(id) == "undefined" ? (active+1)%4 : id);

                $("#panel").animate({"top": tops[active]}, 750);
                $("#main"+prev).fadeOut(750);
                $("#main"+active).fadeIn(750);
            }

            $(function() {
                for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    $("#thumb"+i).attr("src", thumbs[i]);
                    $("#main"+i).attr("src", mains[i]);
                }

                $("#main"+active).show();

                $("img.thumb").mouseover(function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    select($(this).attr("id").substr(-1));
                    timer = setInterval("select()", 5000);
                });

                timer = setInterval("select()", 5000);
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container  {position:relative;}

            #panel      {position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:1;}

            img.thumb   {position:absolute;left:8px;z-index:2;}
            #thumb0     {top:7px;}
            #thumb1     {top:84px;}
            #thumb2     {top:162px;}
            #thumb3     {top:241px;}

            img.main        {position:absolute;left:118px;top:2px;display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="images/panel.png" id="panel" />
            <img id="thumb0" class="thumb" />
            <img id="thumb1" class="thumb" />
            <img id="thumb2" class="thumb" />
            <img id="thumb3" class="thumb" />
            <img id="main0" class="main" />
            <img id="main1" class="main" />
            <img id="main2" class="main" />
            <img id="main3" class="main" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, use `setTimeout(select, 5000);` instead of `"select()"`. `eval()` is evil.

Comment: Having trouble understanding your code, but I think it's most likely a type casting error. A `parseInt(id)` somewhere might just solve the problem.

Comment: @timdream Good point, cheers. I was previously calling it with an argument.

Comment: (1) Pass functions, not strings, to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` (it's `eval` in disguise!). (2) `$(this).attr('id')` is rather unnecessary; `this.id` works in all browsers, takes fewer characters to type, and is much more efficient. (3) In all likelihood, there's a jQuery plugin out there that already does what you want. Even without using a plugin, there's almost certainly a cleaner way to write the `mouseover` handlers.

Comment: @timdream Actually, that parseInt did it, cheers. Must stop being so lazy with my typing. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, a trouble with not using eval() for the setInterval - when I don't use it, it passes an argument, which gets picked up by the function as the id. what is that argument supposed to be. It seems to consist of inconsistent random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` as comment suggested.